# Probability of draw on bets with equal outcomes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gambling

Assume we analyze bets on a game with 3 possible outcomes: win, lose, draw. Let's review bets for teams A and B with 3 possible outcomes:

- Number of bets that A wins = $N_{A}$;
- Number of bets that B wins = $N_{B}$;
- Number of bets on draw = $N_{A,B}$.

Is there any statistical bias towards growing probability for draw when $N_{A}=N_{B}$ ?

**EDIT** (Trying to add more background)

;TLTR; (I try find confirmation that $max(P_{N_{A,B}})$ is when  $N_{A}=N_{B}$ )

Let's start from very simple case, where we have fixed audience = 10000 who make the bets. Fixing the audience makes our N's dependant of each other.  Let's spin random number generator and evaluate $N_A, N_B$ and $N_{A,B}$ as following:

```
na = random.randrange(0, audience)
nb = random.randrange(0, audience - na) # random of the rest of audience
nab = audience - (na + nb) # the rest of audience is draw
```

Following hystogram is obvious (`nab` lays on Z-axis). The max of draws is close to reciprocal minimum of $N_A, N_B$. And "plato" of relativly big number of draws has strong edge near 5000.

[image: random draw distribution depending on varios Na, Nb]

But now Let's make step back to complexity. What if our audience uses some insights (hidden variables) - like a prior knowledge about teams A and B.
Or any participant of audience can make more than 1 bet simultanously.

Can we state then that equality $N_{A}=N_{B}$ also means increase of probability for draw outcome?

**EDIT 2** I went even further, just created script where color (magenta, yellow and silver) plays role of hidden variable that boosts one of $N_{A,B}, N_{A}, N_{B}$. Probability of draw has well visible tendency when $N_{A}, N_{B}$ are close to each other. But how can it be prooven?
[image]

Comment: Hi: The estimate of the probability of a draw is $\frac{N_{AB}}{N_{A} + N_{B} + N_{AB}}$. Note that  $N_{A} + N_{B}$ is constant regardless of the relation between them. I'm not sure if that answers your question because I'm not totally clear on what the question is.

Comment: @markleeds: That assumes that these are just three unrelated results. If we have some model of the situation (say, each team has a strength parameter, and both draws and equidistributed wins are more likely for more similar strengths), then $N_A$ and $N_B$ together could contain more information about the probability of a draw than $N_A+N_B$.

Comment: @Dewfy: The above comments show that the question isn't well-defined as it stands.

Comment: @joriki, - thank you for the comments. Just tried to add some clarification on my question

Comment: @Dewfy: it looks you did a lot of work to make the question clearer. I'll try to say something when I go through it but that's gonna take some time ( given my glance at it. Something came up today ) and, even then, I don't know if I can say something helpful. Hopefully someone else can say something, given your improved question. Thanks to joriki for suggesting to improve the question.